# Solving first order ODE using methods of linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation

$$y'+y=e^{2x}\cos x$$

and I have to use linear algebra methods to find one of its solutions. Also, I have a linear transformation defined the following way

$$\Theta(f)=f'+f$$

whose matrix with respect to basis $\{e^{2x}\cos x,e^{2x}\sin x\}$ I previously found (don't know if it's necessary for this problem), but if we say that D is differentiation operator matrix then matrix of this operator is the sum of D and identity matrix.

Now, the fact that given linear operator is defined similarly as the differential equation surely means something, what I am trying to say  is that if I could find $f$ such that its image is $e^{2x}\cos x$ when mapped using given linear operator, that $f$ would be solution to the given DE. Anyway, I am not quite sure how to do that. Plain guessing isn't good option.

Comment: In what sense is this second order?

Comment: The operator you would want to use would likely be differentiation. If you call it's matrix $\bf D$, then what matrix does $\Theta$ correspond to.

Comment: @Miguel Thanks for pointing my mistake out, i edited it.

Comment: @mathreadler then $$\theta = D + y$$

Comment: $y$ is not an operator. Which is the operator that takes $y\to y$?

Comment: @mathreadler  sorry, i haven't read your comment carefully, you were talking about matrices of operators, then since D is matrix of differentiation operator we have that matrix of $$\theta$$ is sum of D and identity matrix. Right?

Comment: yes! right. now maybe you can figure out what $D$ matrix is? (but I'm quite sure it was big theta wasn't it)?

Comment: @mathreadler Well it's |0  2| first row |-2 0| second row, if we are considering the base given above.

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question with your new found wisdom or even answer your own question when you solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(1,0) \equiv a = e^{2x}\cos x$ and $(0,1) \equiv b = e^{2x}\sin x$,

$$\frac{\partial e^{2x}\cos x}{\partial x} = 2e^{2x}\cos x - e^{2x}\sin x = 2a-b$$

$$\frac{\partial e^{2x}\sin x}{\partial x} = 2e^{2x}\sin x + e^{2x}\cos x = 2b+a$$

So,

$$(1,0) \rightarrow (2,-1) \text{ and } (0,1) \rightarrow (1,2)$$

And,

$$D = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ -1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that $D+I = \begin{pmatrix}3 & 1 \\ -1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$ is invertible and its inverse is $$(D+I)^{-1} = \frac{1}{10}\begin{pmatrix}3 & -1 \\ 1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$

Finally, the required answer is,

$$(D+I)^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{10}\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore,

$$y = \frac{1}{10}(3a + b)$$

P.S. Sorry I studied Linear Algebra long time back. I could have possible written a better answer.

Comment: Ok, i understand this all except for the last part. How is $$(D+I)^{-1}$$ related to the $$y$$? I mean, how can we conclude that if second equation from the bottom is correct, therefore, the last one is correct too?

Comment: $$y' + y = a \equiv Dy + Iy = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix} \iff (D+I)y = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I see now. P.S. Maybe you studied Linear algebra long time ago, but obviously, you still got it. Thank you!